# Decorator design pattern with generic repository

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, design-patterns

I have been looking at the decorator design pattern (I am new to the subject of design patterns).

I am already using BaseRepository pattern. But I want to use some cache too.

Below sample is just a dump example.

So I have **IGenericRepository** interface and the implementation to it.

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    T GetById(int id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id);

    T Add(T entity);
    void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
    Task<T> AddAsync(T entity);
    Task AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<T> entities);

    void Remove(T entity);
    void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);

    int SaveChanges();
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Then I created a custom repository for example **IBlogRepository**

```
public interface IBlogRepository : IBaseRepository<Blog>
{
    public Task<Blog> GetBlogsByCreatorAsync(int creatorId);
}
```

With the implemantation of **BlogRepository**

```
public class BlogRepository : BaseRepository<Blog>, IBlogRepository
{
    public BlogRepository(DbContext db) : base(db)
    {
    }

    public Task<Blog> GetBlogsByCreatorAsync(int creatorId) =>
        db.Blogs.Where(b => b.CreatorId == creatorId)
                .ToListAsync();
}
```

I thought this is cool, then I realised I need to improve my "speed". I am starting use IMemoryCache, but in Repository code like below.

```
public class BlogRepository : BaseRepository<Blog>, IBlogRepository
{
    public BlogRepository(DbContext db, IMemoryCache cache) : base(db)
    {
    }

    public Task<Blog> GetBlogsByCreatorAsync(int creatorId) 
    {
        // if in cache else go to db
    } 
    
}
```

Then I met with Decorate pattern and I thought why not, I started to use it, but I am struggling now. I created **CachedBlogRepository** which is implement **IBlogRepository**, but when I asked to VS implement all interface method...

```
public class CachedBlogRepository : IBlogRepository
{
   //All BaseRepository methods appeared here...
   //But I want cache only the GetBlogsByCreatorAsync method
}
```

So what is the best practice here? Do I missing something or did I something wrong?

Comment: you'll need to implement all the methods or not use inheritance in the interface declaration

Comment: What's the purpose of this code? Solving a real need or "best practices"? You aren't abstracting anything, that's what EF Core does. A DbContext *already* is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work and *multi*-entity repository. A DbSet *already* is a single-entity repository. Your `GetBlogsByCreatorAsync` won't even compile because the code returns `List<Blog>` but the return type is just `Blog`

Comment: you need speed because you have so many clients or few clients making huge amounts or requests? also, because you use the Repository pattern, you always get ALL entities, no filtering on the DB side. Think this through a bit more before you consume gigabytes of memory :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is a place where [CachedRepository pattern](https://ardalis.com/introducing-the-cachedrepository-pattern/) can be used.

I highly recommend you to read this beatuiful article about [Building a CachedRepository in ASPNET Core](https://ardalis.com/building-a-cachedrepository-in-aspnet-core/)

So after applying CachedRepository pattern would look like this:

```
public List<Blog> GetBlogsByCreatorAsync(int id)
{
    string key = MyModelCacheKey + "-" + id;

    return _cache.GetOrCreate(key, entry =>
    {
        entry.SetOptions(cacheOptions);
        return _repository.GetBlogsByCreatorAsync(id);
    });
}
```

You can see [source code at gihub](https://github.com/ardalis/CachedRepository/tree/master/src/CachedRepoSample/Data/Repositories)

Answer (score 0):

First I don't understand this part:

> BlogRepository : BaseRepository, IBlogRepository

shouldn't it be just:

> BlogRepository :  IBlogRepository?

Now when it comes for the Decorator Pattern I would have done this:

```
    public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        T GetById(int id);
        IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
        Task<T> GetByIdAsync(int id);
    
        T Add(T entity);
        void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
        Task<T> AddAsync(T entity);
        Task AddRangeAsync(IEnumerable<T> entities);
    
        void Remove(T entity);
        void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> entities);
    
        int SaveChanges();
        Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
 }
```

(Component)

```
public class BlogRepository : BaseRepository<Blog>, IBlogRepository
{
    public BlogRepository(DbContext db) : base(db)
    {
    }

    public Task<Blog> GetBlogsByCreatorAsync(int creatorId) =>
        db.Blogs.Where(b => b.CreatorId == creatorId)
                .ToListAsync();
}
```

(Concrete Component)

```
abstract class Decorator :  IGenericRepository<T>
{
    protected IGenerecRepository _repository;

    public Decorator( IGenerecRepository repository)
    {
        this._repository = repository;
    }

    public override Task<Blog> GetBlogsByCreatorAsync()
    {
        if (this._repository != null)
        {
            return this._repository.GetBlogsByCreatorAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

(Base Decorator)

```
 class CacheDecorator : Decorator
    {
        public CacheDecorator(IGenericRepository repo) : base(repo)
        {
        }
        public override Task<Blog> GetBlogsByCreatorAsync()
        {
            //cache behavior
        }
    }
```

Uasage:

```
BlogRepository _basicRepo = new BlogRepository();

CacheDecorator _cacheDecorator = new CacheDecorator(_basicRepo);

_cacheDecorator.GetBlogsByCreatorAsync(creatorId);
```

Decorator Pattern adds behavior to the main basic behavior. It needs a wrappee (the basic component) to wrap new behavior around it.